# Details on partial oracle computability in Ganov

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, computability-theory

I'm currently glancing at a couple papers by V. A. Ganov ([*Recursion on generalized computable ordinals*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00975165) and [*A generalized constructable continuum*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00969904)), and I'm running into some basic issues. Ganov variously restricts attention to oracles $F$ with properties which seem dubious to me:

- In the first paper, Ganov looks at $F$ such that the set of indices for $F$-computable well-founded trees is $F$-c.e.
- In the second paper, Ganov looks at $F$ such that a variant of the halting problem for $F$ is $F$-decidable.

Now admittedly Ganov's oracles are **partial** functions, and there are definitely subtleties that crop up when using partial rather than total oracles. My question is: what is a good source for partial oracles which covers their usage in Ganov's articles?